# Setting value in html element from external js

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage. It takes input phone number and search in the directory if the number is stored or not. Then shows the name of the people and the phone number.
I'm doing this with html and javascript. The search result is set by the external js file. But the problem is after setting the value in

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
```

it just shows and disappears in less than 1 second.
how to solve this problem ?
here is my html code-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Eureca </title>
    <link href="../Student Info Search Engine/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
     <div class="header"> </div>
     <div class="container">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="search" onChange="func1()"> <br/>
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Search"> </button>
        </form>
        <!-- <p id="result"> </p> -->
     </div>
     <div class="result"> </div>
     <script src="../Student Info Search Engine/design.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
</body>
```

here is the javascript code-

```
function func1(){

    var str;
    var students=[];
    str=document.getElementById("search").value;
    if(str[0]=='+'){
        alert("Invalid format");
        return;
    }

    if(str.length>=2){
        if(isnum(str)){
            //alert("The number is "+str);
            if(str[0]=='0' && str[1]=='1' && str.length<=11){
                var res,i,out=[];
                out=phone(str);
                res="";
                for(i=0;i<out.length;i++){
                    res+=out[i].name+" "+out[i].phn+"\n";
                }
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
            }
            else if(str[0]=='1' && (str[1]=='3' || str[1]=='4') && str.length<=7){

            }
            else{
                alert("Invalid input");
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("The text is "+str);
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Please enter at least 2 characters");
    }
}
```

i didn't post full js code, because it will make the post very long.

Comment: Sidenote: your input tag is html, while your br tag is xhtml.

Comment: is that the reason of this problem ??? actually i'm not very good at this yet. :/

Comment: No, it's just not gonna validate, but the browsers don't care about it.

Comment: is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: if you can make a fiddle of this  with all the code necessary to reproduce the problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Just added one more button which is taking the output from a function and assigning it to `innerHTML`. I added this one line of code-

```
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Show Result" onClick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = show_result()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try just to replace `<button id="btn"> Search </button>` with `<input type="button" id="btn" value = "Search"></button>`

Comment: same. the result just disappears. :(

Comment: <p id="result"> </p> change to div element

Comment: In your JavaScript you have if(isnum(str)) replace that with  if(!isNaN(str))

Answer (score 1):

If your problem with disappearing value after click submit button then here is solution:

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta content="">
        <style></style>
      </head>
      <body class="background-color">
          <div class="header"> </div>
             <div class="container">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" id="search" onChange="func1()"> <br/>
                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="func1()">Submit</a>
                </form>
                <p id="result"> </p>
             </div>
      </body>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script >
      function func1(){

        var str = [];
        var students=[];
        str=document.getElementById("search").value;
        if(str[0]=='+'){
            alert("Invalid format");
            return;
        }

        if(str.length>=2){
            if(str){
                //alert("The number is "+str);
                if(str[0]=='0' && str[1]=='1' && str.length<=11){
                    var res,i,out=[];
                    out=str;
                    res="";
                    for(i=0;i<out.length;i++){
                        res+="name" +" "+"number"+"\n";
                    }
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=res;
                }
                else if(str[0]=='1' && (str[1]=='3' || str[1]=='4') && str.length<=7){

                }
                else{
                    alert("Invalid input");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("The text is "+str);
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("Please enter at least 2 characters");
        }
    }
      </script>
    </html>
```

I added this instead of button:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="func1()">Submit</a>
```

Here is example on  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqpfdn6q/)

Comment: can't i do it with a button ?

Comment: it's also doing the same thing. :(

Comment: What you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm trying to show the search result below the search box, but the result is disappearing.